# Do I need Inertia to use Laravel + React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I want to move app and I am looking to new technologies. I have no experience with Laravel, but I wonder if I want to create a Laravel + React web app do I also need to look at Inertia, or I can do Laravel + React without Inertia?

Answer (score 6):

**NO.** You can build an app with Laravel and React as your front-end without Inertia.

**HOWEVER**, if you're looking into building an SPA, I'd recommend looking into Inertia, since it makes the process of integrating the back-end and front-end a lot easier and you won't need to write an API to get them talking to each other.

Answer (score 4):

Backing up a bit @Matheus 's answer.

The purpose of Inertia is to be able to create an SPA application using the laravel routing system.
You can create your routes in your `web.php`, that would point to a `Controller`'s function and that function would return a `React` component with your data as props.

This takes away a lot of work on both sides. Without inertia you would need a frontend application made in this case with `React`, then `useEffect` would be responsible for calling an api in your laravel application to then retrieve just the data so you can use it on your frontend application.

Either way is possible, although if you are a fullstack taking care of both, the frontend and backend I recommend Inertia to save yourself some time and `CSRF token` pain :)

Answer (score 0):

You can build an App with Laravel + React without using Inertia. You don't even need to create API routes for that App to work, because you can perfectly use the normal web routes and even load blade views (optionally). Either webpack or vite are fine to manage your css/js files.  CSRF is managed automatically by Laravel and Axios, so there are not complications to play without Inertia as long as you know how to install Laravel and React properly in the same repository and create the right web routes for the case.